# Cómo pedir ser página de inicio en un navegador

Tags: javascript, html, navegador-web

Quisiera saber cómo hago para que mi página web pida ser la página de inicio del navegador, así como lo hace Google que te pregunta si deseas que su página sea la de inicio y si le das aceptar puff listo ya es de inicio predeterminada en tu navegador.

Comment: Hola Cesar Arreaza, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. También te sugiero revisar la sección de [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

No es posible hacer esto mediante código en la mayoría de los navegadores como medida de seguridad. Si así fuera, cualquier sitio web que visite podría convertirse automáticamente en su página de inicio sin su consentimiento.

El hecho de que las versiones anteriores de IE te permiten hacer esto es una gran excepción y no una regla.

Si de todas formas necesitas esta funcionalidad, deberías escribir una guía paso a paso para indicar a las personas en qué parte de la barra de herramientas hacer clic y dónde establecer su página de inicio en la configuración de su navegador.

---

*Tomado de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751036/cross-browser-script-to-make-my-website-as-home-page?lq=1) en inglés*

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer soportaba

```
document.setHomePage('http://example.com')
```

pero dicha funcionalidad fue retirada.

No hay una forma estándar para todos los navegadores.

Preguntas similares en inglés

- [Set default home page in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/438108/1595451)
- [Is setHomePage still supported in Internet Explorer 11 and/or Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31679762/1595451)